# Terraform resource Elastic Load Balancer - reduce ConnectionDrainingPolicy timeout

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

Would like to reduce ConnectionDrainingPolicy (CloudFormation term) Timeout (default is 300), but can not find an argument in list https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lb.html that allows to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS ELBs are different from LBs/ALBs. ConnectionDrainingPolicy is an ELB concept.

Look at the `aws_elb` resource type and the 
`connection_draining` and `connection_draining_timeout` attributes.

Resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb-connectiondrainingpolicy.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#connection_draining

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#connection_draining_timeout

Comment: as I understand it is for "classic" lb only, not alb